# To subscribe to the leadgen field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval

Tags: facebook

I am integrating facebook leads in my CRM, like I can get leads from Facebook Pages on behalf of my client's.

I am encountering this error.

> To subscribe to the leadgen field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval

I have standard access for 'leads_retrival'. Advanced access can be achieved after hitting the API at least one time.

Answer (score 0):

you need a token that has advanced access to leads_retrival.  To get such a token, you can go to the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and then you can add permissions of leads_retrival. Permission can be added in the right middle of the tool and you can add them for testing purposes as you can see in the picture. . [image]

Once you add the permissions, then you can click on **generate access token**, and a popup will open from Facebook, you have to allow a few things and then you can use that access token for hitting the API for testing purposes. Then you can apply for advanced API access.

Comment: Is there a way to create such token from a get request, so that it already has all required permissions?

Comment: No, there is no get request. Basically, you have to make an app and that app has to take permissions. You can check this link for permissions.
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/)

The Complete process of getting permissions to use their APIs can be found on the above given link.